# Tcpdump stop ungracefully

Tags: networking, wireshark, tcpdump

I am looking for a reliable solution to do package capture for test automation.

Right now, tcpdump has been used with the following command.

```
sudo tcpdump -i ens160  -w filename.pcap -G 60 -W 1
```

I stop tcpdump with:

```
kill -s SIGINT <pid>
```

1 out of 20 time tcpdump fails to exit properly, and the pcap file will be damaged.

Is there any way to make sure tcpdump will exit properly?

Comment: Why not never issue the `kill` command? The tcpdump command will terminate gracefully after a maximum of one minute anyhow, with a complete and not corrupted pcap file.

Comment: The time is a secondary defense level only to make sure, tcpdump will be terminated even if someone terminate the test execution. I do not know all the time how long the test will run, only know what is the worst case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to avoid a truncated dump file:

1. As suggested by Doug Smythies, use termination signal (`SIGTERM`) instead of `SIGINT` to kill the `tcpdump` process:

   ```
   kill <pid>
   ```
2. Tell `tcpdump` to write packet directly to file as each packet is saved (option `-U`). This way, even using SIGINT, the file will not be truncated. From [man tcpdump](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) :

> ```
>    -U
>    --packet-buffered
>           If the -w option is not specified, make the  printed  packet
>           output  ``packet-buffered''; i.e., as the description of the
>           contents of each packet is printed, it will  be  written  to
>           the standard output, rather than, when not writing to a ter‐
>           minal, being written only when the output buffer fills.
>
>           If the -w option is specified, make  the  saved  raw  packet
>           output  ``packet-buffered'';  i.e., as each packet is saved,
>           it will be written to the output  file,  rather  than  being
>           written only when the output buffer fills.
>
>           The  -U flag will not be supported if tcpdump was built with
>           an older version of libpcap that lacks the pcap_dump_flush()
>           function.
> ```